# unmanaged array marshaling and size as pointer

Tags: c#, .net, interop, unmanaged

I want to call an unmanaged C function from C# code, the call itself works fine, but then I need to make a callback to C# code. I have a function with the following signature in C++:

```
SRes Read(void *p, void *buf, size_t *size);
```

I have written a corresponding delegate to look like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int StreamRead(IntPtr ptr, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] byte[] buffer, ref int bytes);
```

Unfortunately the application crashes (`System.AccessViolationException`) when trying to execute callback. The parameters look reasonable, the only possible issue that comes to mind is that the size of the array is incorrectly read. With the above marshaling specification, will size of the array be read from `size` or `*size`? If the former then how to change it to the latter? If this is not the reason of the crash then what else might be the problem here? It is also worth noting that after removing the `MarshalAs` attribute the call succeeds, but my array is of size 1.

Comment: Changing value of size parameter in debugger from memory location to 32 in fact makes the call succeed and the array is size 32. But I still do not know how to force the interop classes read the array length from *size.

Comment: The data flow is very unclear.  Who is supposed to create the array?

Comment: On high level C# calls C++ which calls back into C#. The C++ code allocates the array and expects C# code to fill it upto *size bytes. However, if not enough data is available then the C# code may modify *size to indicate that.

Comment: Well, that's not something that the marshaller would understand.  It will assume that the size argument indicates actual array size.  Kaboom if that is not the case.  You'll need to re-think this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I hoped for something better, the following workaround works ok:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int StreamRead(IntPtr ptr, byte* buffer, int* bytes);
```

If you know how to make it work with byte[], please share.